# How can I stop 'in use' message from intermittently blocking my wp_posts table?

Tags: posts, database, bug

How can I stop the 'in use' message from intermittently occurring in **phpMyAdmin** `wp_posts` table?

I have no warnings and no error messages prior, but when it happens to my `wp_posts` table, all my content is blocked from loading. A repair table always fixes it, but this is a temporary fix until it happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If repairing the table fixes it, you can schedule a repair database as often as needed, I use a plugin called [WP-DBManager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dbmanager/), after installation go to **Database > DB Options** and find **Automatic Scheduling**, you will have to work on **Automatic Repairing Of DB**, I think every hour is ok, not so often but often enough.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm going to try your suggestion and hopefully it will help resolve the problem.

Comment: Great. Mark the answer as correct when it happens.